# updating part of sql column value with random-ish string

Tags: mysql

I need to randomise several hundred thousand email addresses. Strictly speaking they only need to be anonymised, but ideally they need to be unique.

I know I can generate a fairly random string by selecting a unix time stamp with

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();)
```

So where I'm going next is to replace everything before the @ with such a string, and then replace everything after the string with `@anonymised.com`.

The part I'm stuck at is how to insert the unix timestamp into the specific part of the email address. I know I can get the characters to the left of the @ symbol with

```
LEFT(email,INSTR(email,"@")-1)
```

and I know I can use the REPLACE command to replace part of a string, but combining the two like this does NOT work....

```
UPDATE USERS SET email = REPLACE(LEFT(email,INSTR(email,"@")-1), UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

I'm guessing that replace is expecting a string rather than a function, but cannot figure where to go from here....

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? It generates an error? It generates a result different from expected? ...?

Comment: Sorry, yes it generated a syntax error. Thanks for looking, I have found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the solution was as simple as

```
update employees set email =  CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() , '@anonymised.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:
`SELECT CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),SUBSTR(email,INSTR(email,'@'))) FROM USERS`?

If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() doesn't fulfill your requirements, take a look at https://www.cemgokmen.com/random-unique-string-generation-using-mysql/

Cheers, J.